# Flexbox text overflow w/ellipsis

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to use CSS3 `flex` to have my first column stop wrapping and truncate the text when it reaches the height of the second column. So, ideally, all of the text in column two is visible always, and column one takes up whatever space is available to it instead of wrapping on the first line, but column 1 should never be allowed to set the height of the whole `flex` div itself.

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjyJZK

Comment: This may help: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: This is a really great resource, but it seems to just discuss ways to get your text to clamp. It seems like there may not be a way to dynamically break your text without something like jQuery to truncate by number of characters, or something similar

Comment: AFAIK the `text-overflow: ellipsis` method only works on one-line text.

Comment: Flexbox isn't intended intended to be for that, the whole line-clamp thing was a webkit only feature.